# Install4j: installing a service

Tags: java, postgresql, windows-services, install4j

For my installation, I am trying to install both my database server (which is postgresql) and my application server as services. I know it is possible to install `postgres` using `pg_ctl` from console by starting it as admin. But as far I know it is not possible for java to start `cmd.exe` in administrative mode. So I was hoping to be able to achieve it by Install4j. I saw the sample "hello" project. But there it creates a launcher. But in my case for postgresql I need to run the pg_ctl along with some arguments. And for application server I have my own batch file as the executor. For PGSQL I have tried giving windows arguments i.e. `-N service_name -D data_folder`. But for both cases it fails to start the service. I also tried manually from the Services menu in Windows it fails to start. I have the account setting as "local system".

I have also tried running `pg_ctl` using "run executable or batch file" action but still I could not find the service in the windows services list, not to mention the same arguments work fine from `command prompt`. I have added a figure of the action properties I used in the project.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your installer has executed a "Request privileges" action and you execute pg_ctl.exe with a "Run executable or batch file" action, it will be executed with admin privileges, because the the default value of the "Action elevation type" property of that action is "Elevate to maximum available privileges".

Comment: ok. But what does this option "working directory" exactly refer to in "Run executable or batch file" action? Also, suppose I am able to do this for postgres but what about my batch file that I want to register/install as a windows service?

Comment: The working directory is likely irrelevant, you can set it to "." (without the quotes). A batch file cannot function as a Windows service.

Comment: I tried the "Run executable or batch file" action, but still could not make it work. For better details I have edited my question.

Comment: In the configuration of the action, you should redirect stderr and stdout to the log file and analyze the output of the pg_ctl command.